# NoSQL data modeling

Tags: nosql, bigdata, data-modeling

I know various data models in NoSQL are key-value store, graph store, column store and document store. 
My question is whether **Data modeling and modeling techniques in NoSQL are same**?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily same for all types of nosql databases.